# Swift TableView cell doesn't fit into 1 row

Tags: swift, layout, swift2, tableview

I'm working on a swift project. I have a tableview that loads the data correctly. However, I have many cells for each row and it doesn't fit into the iphone screen, and got cut off the screen. I would like to have some cells go on to the next line instead of not showing on the screen. How to do that? Thanks.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ResultTableViewCell

    //cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

    //cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

    let category: Category = categories[indexPath.row]

    cell.lblName.text = category.name
    cell.lblQty.text = category.qty
    cell.lblSub.text = category.sub
    cell.lblSub2.text = category.sub2
    cell.lblCountry.text = category.country
    cell.lblState.text = category.state
    cell.lblCity.text = category.city


    return cell

}
```

On my screen, it can only fit 5 columns, and the rest gets cut off. I want to show each row in 2 lines. The first line will display the name, qty, sub, sub2 and the next line will display country, state and city.

Comment: Please post your code so we can understand what's going on.

Comment: I pasted the code.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't tell us much without seeing the layout of your cells and some example screens presenting the issue. But it's possible that you would want to look at autoresizing cells and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.